# What is it called when a non-verb is used as a verb?

Tags: single-word-requests, antimeria

This is in very common use on the internet. I just read this:

> "[The] hotel employee walks in, I say "uh, puppy" and she just **NOPEd** the [heck] out of the room."

This is often done by adding *'d* to the word.

Comment: They verbed it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can “duct tape” be used as a verb?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31170/can-duct-tape-be-used-as-a-verb)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think the term you are looking for is ["verbification":](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbification#Verbing)

> Verbification, or verbing, is the creation of a verb from a noun, adjective or other word. Verbification is a type of functional shift. It is also a form of derivation, and may involve any of the various derivational processes.

This is a process of conversion of a word to include more word-classes for the lexicon.
  This applies to any non-verb, even "proper nouns":

> Proper nouns can also be verbed in the English language. "Google" is the name of a popular internet search engine. To google something now means to look it up on the internet, as in "He didn't know the answer, so he googled it."

That's a favourite, "google" is.

Comment: I'm kind of disappointed that it's such a straight-forward term. Oh well, perfect answer.

Comment: @Jeremy, the truth hurts :)

Comment: +1 for Google as the prime example. You could have just told him to google it, and see if he caught the reference.

Comment: "Verbing weirds language." is *my* personal favorite.

Comment: I just saw this example and I was horrified:  

"The governor’s stay-at-home order turned downtown Seattle into a “ghost town,” said Rachel Marshall, owner of Rachel’s Ginger Beer, who opened a location near the Amazon Spheres late last year. Without a strong summer season, Marshall said, low-margin businesses like restaurants can’t survive. “**It just doesn’t pencil**,” she added."

Answer (score 14):

As others have said, "verbification" is common. The highfalutin Greek name of the more general concept of using a word as the "wrong" part of speech is [anthimeria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthimeria).

See also [Calvin's opinion](http://bookishmonkey.files.wordpress.com/2007/09/verbing-weirds-language1.jpg) on the subject.

Comment: That comic was *awesome*.

Answer (score 6):

Verbification, or verbing. See Wikipedia's entry on [linguistic conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_%28linguistics%29).

Answer (score 6):

When any lexeme changes its word class without affixation, the process is known as ‘conversion’.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I believe the word you are looking for is *anthimeria*.  From

> In rhetoric, **anthimeria**, traditionally and more properly called **antimeria** (from the Greek: *ἀντί*, *antí*, “against, opposite” and *μέρος*, *méros*, “part”), is the use of a word as if it were a member of a different word class (part of speech); typically, the use of a noun as if it were a verb.