# Verbing, or turning nouns into verbs

Tags: verbs, neologisms, syntactic-analysis, antimeria

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is it called when a non-verb is used as a verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42666/what-is-it-called-when-a-non-verb-is-used-as-a-verb)

The phenomenon of turning a noun into a verb is very common. Some are more well known, like "shouldering the blame" or "tabling a discussion," while others are newer and less known. I just came across "when it storms." Is there a real name for this or is it just called "verbing?" If not, what was it called before the word "verbing" was coined?

Comment: @MattЭллен The questions are certainly related but I think this is asking something slightly different - are there alternatives to "verbing" / what was it called before "verbing"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The phenomenon of verbing spans several other, slightly broader phenomena - some of which intersect or are subsets of one another.

- **[Anthimeria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthimeria)** is the *rhetorical* use of a word as if it were a member of a different word class. I would expect that most examples of verbing begin as rhetorical devices.
- **[Conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_%28linguistics%29)**, also called **zero derivation**, is the creation of a word from an existing word without any change in form. ("I will *table* this")
- If a new word is formed "(I am *tabling* this") this is an example of **[derivation,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_%28linguistics%29)** the process of forming a new word on the basis of an existing word
- Because changing the class of a word changes the syntax of the word, all of these are examples of a **[functional shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_shift)**, which occurs when an existing word takes on a new syntactic function.

So it would appear that there isn't a term synonymous with "verbing" that was used before that term was coined, but I would expect one or more of the above would have been used to describe the phenomenon.

Of course the word "verbing" is itself an example of verbing!

Answer (score 6):

The OED cites "verbify" from 1878 and "verb" as a verb from 1936.

Linguists have the adjective (and sometimes noun) "deverbal" to mean a word that has been formed from a verb.

Note that in many languages verbing requires some morphological change to the word  because verbs have a different shape from other words. In English, content words do not show their role by their shape, so you can often verb a noun without any change to it (as there).

Comment: What do you mean by "verbs have a different shape" and showing a role by shape?

Comment: In many languages words take a variety of endings (or other morphological processes) that depend on their part of speech. This is true to a limited extend in English (if you add "-ing", it must be a verb), but the bare form of a word is often used, both for nouns and for verbs. In French, for example, most forms of a verb have distinctive endings. There _are_ forms of verbs which could function as nouns (often the first or third person singular present), but most forms would look wrong as a noun.

Comment: Ah yes. Didn't know it was called 'shape.' Nice insight.

Comment: It isn't. I was using that as a non-technical term.