# Is there a verb form for "Template", or such synonym?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, verbs, synonyms

My research shows that the word Template exists only as a noun.

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/template?s=t)

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/template)

[The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/template)

I feel comfortable using the word to Template, or Templating (as a verb or gerund), to express the process of creating a template, though it doesn't exist...

Or is there a good word to describe this that *does* exist?

My need is a bit tricky - I'm referring to a process where you create a template and then create documents based on it. So perhaps we could say:

> Start the Document (templating/other word) process.

Comment: Model, guide, plan, coin, create.... How do you plan to use the word in a sentence? What is your objection to "create a template"?

Comment: You can verb any noun. *Template*, like *stencil*, can be used as a verb.

Comment: @MarkHubbard - I've edited the question

Comment: @Drew - can you back that up with something?

Comment: Is the essence here that you are trying to make two processes, template creation and document creation from a template, into one process, with a name?

Comment: Sure: use it as a verb and it will be a verb. Perfectly understandable to any English speaker. No problem. If you want to wait a few years after you've used it and spread it around, and then read about it as a verb in the OED, then wait.

Comment: @Drew - cute. i happen to agree with you, but i'm wondering if this is a documented and/or common method of verbing (a verb i just made up)

Comment: Sorry, I have no documentation for you.

Comment: @Spagirl - i believe so

Comment: @Drew: I think you've pretty much [***solutioned***](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67242/is-solutioning-a-correct-word/67250) OP's problem there! :)

Comment: "Start the Document Template process" sounds fine to me. Why create a new verb?

Comment: @MarkHubbard, other than the excitement of building the English language, I'm really looking for a process name (which i used in the sentence, for the sake of a sample sentence)

Comment: "**Start the Document Template process**" sounds fine to me. Why create a new verb?

Comment: Sigh. OK, **plating** has become standard usage in the **culinary** community, so you might as well introduce **templating** in the (**what? Microsoft Word?**) community. It just grates a little. ;-)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Wouldn't that be "dissolved"?

Comment: "Templatize" is a reasonably common informal verb meaning "form into a template" or "extract a template from".

Comment: If you want support for @Drew's assertion, comics have you covered: [Calvin and Hobbes](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/362469469982721374/),  [Get Fuzzy](http://www.gocomics.com/getfuzzy/2003/04/27), [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/1443/)

Comment: @AlMaki Just *solved*.

Answer (score 3):

**Templatize** is sometimes used in the computer industry, to refer to the process of creating a template from some example.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/templatize

Answer (score 2):

***Modeling*** (in the sense of *creating a model or template*) should come close.

dictionary.com:

> **[model](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/model?s=t)**
>   *verb* (used without object), modeled, modeling or (especially British) modelled, modelling.
>   **22**. to make models

Answer (score 2):

*Template* as a verb is well established in a few areas, such as replacing boat cushion covers.

> The more precise the pattern you provide will result in a more exact fitting boat cushion. (For local customers we'll come and **template** every boat cushion needed for a flat $150 fee.)

http://www.foamorder.com/cushions/boat-cushions.html

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the verb form?

'Create a template'

'Create a document using the (a) template'