# Can a noun can be used as a verb for an idiom?

Tags: phrases, idioms, verbing, antimeria

Is there really an idiom called "don't playground with us" which is similar to don't mess with us? I often found slang in movie/series that a noun can be used as verb also like "Let's *chair* him up" or "You only want my sister to *bed* her". Is that common for an idiom, and is it often used in daily conversation even though not grammatically correct?

Comment: Please remember to use a capital letter at the start of a sentence. I have corrected your question.

Comment: Unlike *playground*, *bed* and *chair* are also verbs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Verbing, or turning nouns into verbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44223/verbing-or-turning-nouns-into-verbs)

Answer (score 2):

It is ***[don't play (around)](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/don%27t+play+around+with+me)** with someone*:

> - Do not try to trick me or tell me a lie; do not try to make a fool out of me; don't try to manipulate my emotions.
> - *Listen, pal, don't play around with me! Either pay your debts on time or we'll have to repossess your home. Don't play with me—did I win the award or not?*

(The Free Dictionary)