# Can “adulting” be considered a verb, or is it only ever a noun?

Tags: verbs, nouns, parts-of-speech, syntactic-analysis, verbing

I know the word has exploded in popularity in recent times, but I'm not sure how to use it right.

[This TIME article](http://time.com/4361866/adulting-definition-meaning/) considers the word a verb, so does [this M-W blog](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/adulting). However, the [ODO entry](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/adulting) only mentions it as a mass noun or a modifier, conspicuously leaving out any mention of verbs:

> *informal*
>
> **[mass noun]** The practice of behaving in a way characteristic of a responsible adult, especially the accomplishment of mundane but necessary tasks:
>
> *‘it feels really good to take a step back from adulting and have someone else cook dinner for me’*
>
> **[as modifier]** *‘I finished all my adulting requirements for the week’*

I recognize that one dictionary entry doesn't prove/disprove anything. Still, if I think about it, I have to agree with ODO; because to me, sentences like:

> - I hate adulting.

sound idiomatic, but when I try to frame sentences that use it blatantly as a verb, like:

> - I adulted yesterday and I hated it.
> - I need to adult tomorrow and I'm not looking forward to it.

I'm not sure if they're idiomatic. My questions are:

1. Can *adulting* be considered a verb, or is it just a noun?
2. Do these sentences sound right, usage-wise?
3. Are they grammatically correct?

Thoughts?

Comment: ***Adulting***  was 2014 Word of the Year: it appears  that *AdultingBlog.com* is responsible for its usage. http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/2014-word-of-the-year-adulting

Comment: @JOSH: It's popular, but somehow, I feel the word has slipped through the cracks of pop culture. Since I'm not from an Anglophone country, my primary source for the latest trends in English are movies and TV shows. (I remember 'Bad Moms' teaching me a lot about the word 'entitled' last year) But I don't recall hearing this word used even a single time. In fact, a hashtag, like in the posts from your link, seems to be it's primary use-case.

Comment: ***Verbing Nouns***: *Lindsey also said she and her friends like making nouns into verbs. “Everyone adds -ing to words,” she says. They talk about internetting, Facebooking, and when they’re watching the TV show Supernatural, they’re Supernaturaling.*

Comment: Adulting as a verb is just one of the many examples  from the trend of verbing  nouns. https://oupeltglobalblog.com/tag/nouns-used-as-verbs/ - I'd personally not use it as a verb.

Comment: I could have sworn this strip was older, 'verbing weirds language' http://www.gocomics.com/calvinandhobbes/2013/01/28

Comment: @Spagirl: How have I not read that one before despite reading almost all of _C&H_? I hate myself :) [Btw, it probably is older and was only syndicated on the day shown.]

Comment: @TusharRaj Who knows what the original date is, it can't have been 2013, he stopped drawing them in 1995, which suggests that weirding the language by verbing was prevalent then.

Comment: @Spagirl Right you are. Still, it's like finding gold.

Comment: [What is verbing?](http://grammar.about.com/od/grammarfaq/f/verbingfaq.htm) and @Spagirl this [Calvin Hobbes cartoon](http://www.gocomics.com/calvinandhobbes/1993/01/25/) says it's 1993

Answer (score 2):

There are many posts on ELU dealing with *verbification* or *verbing* which is

> the creation of a verb from a noun, adjective or other word.

[Source: [What is it called when a non-verb is used as a verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42666/what-is-it-called-when-a-non-verb-is-used-as-a-verb)]

The noun *science* could be used as a verb as the following question indicates.

> [“To science the sh*t out of something”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/305782/to-science-the-sht-out-of-something)

Verbification depends on whether a sentence using it is understandable or not. "To science the shit out of something" makes sense and to adult as a verb can make a sense, but it is not any more popular than using *science* as a verb. I think it is only used in a title or hashtag. You need to note that to *adult* can mean to *grow up* or *take responsibility* as in

> How families can help kids learn to 'adult'.

[Source: [CNBC.com](http://www.cnbc.com/2016/10/06/how-families-can-help-kids-learn-to-adult.html)]