# Can "brain" be used as a verb

Tags: verbs, language-evolution, verbing

tv commercial for a brain supplement asks, "Would you like to brain better?"

Comment: They verbed it, although it is already a verb with a different meaning.  https://english.stackexchange.com/q/42666/36710

Comment: brain-storm; brain-drain as compound verbs as well as nouns. A synonym to OP's question could be 'cerebrate'.

Comment: [Brain (transitive verb)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brain#h2): "**1** : to kill by smashing the skull; **2** : to hit on the head."

Answer (score 1):

Brain has long been used as a verb. To hit someone over the head with a cudgel is *to Brain* them. This is something I consider doing to people when I see they are *Verbing* things into existence rather than use the words already available.

Answer (score 0):

Typically no, but the context is that they are making a play on words against "train", so it works in this scenario.

Answer (score -1):

It is not a verb, no, but in informal language, it could be used as one. For example, saying would you like to (noun) better would indicate using whatever the noun is better.

Comment: It ***is*** a defined verb, just not in the intransitive sense used in the question.