# Is the term "errored out" a grammatically correct phrase, or just a colloquial one?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, phrasal-verbs

I was wondering whether it is OK to use "errored out" as part of a status message in my code — is it grammatically correct to use it, or is there a better choice of words that I can use in its place?

Comment: Can you share your status message in full, for context?

Comment: "Training has errored out" ...

Comment: I like the phrase 'The code is erroring out', but it's a preference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Errored out" is grammatically correct ([*errored*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/error) is the simple past and past participle of error) but it's relatively new, not very commonly used and may still be considered slang, so I'd advise against using it.

Depending on your actual context, use something else such as "Encountered an error at line 20", or simply just "Error: line 20".

See also this related question: [Is “errored” correct usage?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/3059/9001)