# How is the past tense of "error" spelt in British English?

Tags: british-english, orthography, programming, doubled-consonants

How is the past tense of "error" spelt in British English?

Wiktionary [says](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/error#English) that it's "errored", but its entry for [errored](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/errored#English) doesn't explicitly say it's valid for British English, and I thought it'd get another "r" compared to American English.

This question is not a duplicate of [Is "errored" correct usage?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3059/is-errored-correct-usage) , because this is asking about spelling, and the other question is about whether using "error" as a verb is "correct" from a prescriptivist perspective.

Comment: I think both AmE and BrE prefer "*erred*".

Comment: Since *error* is a noun derived from the verb *to err*, I must agree with Dan Bron; I have simply never seen *error* used as a verb.

Comment: @Mari-LouA there wasn't a strong consensus that "error" can't be verbed.

Comment: Could you provide an example sentence with the "verb" to error? Are you asking if in BrEng it should be written as "errorred"?  Why should the letter -r be doubled? *To pepper* (past) *peppered*

Comment: @Mari-LouA No, yes.

Comment: What do you mean by "no" that you cannot provide a sentence example? Why were you interested in its spelling then? (*mouse hovers perilously over down arrow at this point*)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't appreciate threats.

Comment: It was intended as a form of humour, a nudge, a joke. I should add smileys :) :) :)

Comment: If this is not a duplicate of the question mentioned because it is asking about spelling, it's still off topic. Where's your evidence that BrEng spells it as *errorred*? You're basing your question on a false premise. NOT my downvote.

Answer (score 3):

According to oxford, [error](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/error) isn't a verb.

[Err](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/err) is, and here are its forms:

[image]

Not to knock wiktionary, but I wouldn't consider errored a verb form. Note that [the entry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/errored#English) doesn't cite any examples for this sense. Its examples as an adjective seem passable, though, especially in a technical sense.

> *The mean number of errored bits per errored symbol is therefore...*

Comment: I suspect the  "errored" bits were actually "erroneous", perhaps due to being "corrupted" in transmission. Anyway, +1 for a good answer. One Wiktionary example does not make it proper usage.

Comment: Fwiw, OED also has [*error* as a verb](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/64127) but with a rather specific use regarding court decisions.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: This is embarrassing. I blame muscle memory :)

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist It it worth noting, though, that they only cite it as being included in the 1828 Webster dictionary. Tellingly, the 1913 Webster does not have it.

Comment: Of course [*to error* does not mean *to err*](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/3068/300). That's why it exists in the first place. A program that errors does not err. In fact it probably functions precisely the way you wrote it. You may have erred, but the program errors.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: Or the program encounters an error, as the top answer to your linked question proposes, and as most people around me put it.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Been a while since my programming days, but we never used *error* as a verb that way. We did use *to segfault* in a similar sense, and on occasion *errored out*, and of course *threw an error* was a commonly-seen synonym for *threw an exception*, but much more frequently programs *choked*, *croaked*, *died*, etc. Why, in the good old days of Perl, those were even keywords (as was *carp*)!

Comment: @Dan: yes, same here, but that's sort of beside the point. When the program segfaults, or chokes, or freezes, or dies, or errors out, or throws an exception, that still does not mean that it *errs*. It might or might not err. It only errs if it errors erroneously.

Answer (score 0):

The entry for *error (v)* in OED has not been updated since 1891. As such, it's unlikely to include modern usages which arise from computing. Even the Oxford Dictionary of Computing is now six years old, which is rather a long time in the field.

***Error*** is used as a verb. It's jargon, and means "produce an error message" or "fail with an error condition" or some such similar event.

> 3. (verb) What a program does when it stops as result of a programming error.
>
> [FOLDOC](http://foldoc.org/error)

Because it's computing jargon, it would probably sound out of place when used in other circumstances. It would be incorrect to say that I had *errored* in constructing this answer.

Computing jargon is generally spelled with American spellings, even in British English. *Program* and its derivatives are the obvious examples; many languages' verbs are spelled with a *-z-* spelling (like Oracle's `ANALYZE` function). Consequently, even if British English doubled the consonant for *errorred* it would be unlikely to persist.

In fact, there are rules for the doubling of consonants in English [see [another ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4791/focussed-or-focused-the-double-consonant)]. There may be exceptions to those rules, but

- *error* doesn't appear to be an exception (ends in schwa, so final consonant stays single);
- its usage comes directly from American English (AmE doubles consonants far more rarely);
- there is no separate entry in Wiktionary or FOLDOC indicating a transatlantic difference.

Comment: Is the spelling of past tense of ‘prefer’ identical in both dialects (BrEng and AmEng); i.e. **preferred**? Is there a single case where the letter -r is not doubled before the suffix-ed in AmEng? I can't think of one.

Comment: If you can answer this, I'll retract my vote to close this question. The downvote is not mine.

Comment: I couldn't say about AmE. The final syllable of *prefer* is accented (so not a schwa) in BrE, so the consonant is doubled. But a single case you ask for is *errored.*

Comment: In that case, I don't understand your point.

Comment: Yes, but the spelling is the same for AmEng and BrEng. That's my point. Compare AmEng *traveled* and BrEng *travelled*, which is well documented. Most dictionaries list their different spellings. My point being that the OP is asking about a different way of spelling (errored), which he already found in a dictionary, and yet asks if BrEng spells it differently. He's done the research but he believes the opposite is true, based on what?

Comment: Aha. I see; yes, *travelled* is an apparent exception, which is presumably covered by the "It's like that just because it is" rule! I'll adjust the answer; it would have been helpful if the downvoter had actually said what wasn't useful.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: the "r" is not doubled in "powered," "centered," "murdered," "answered." There are lots of examples.

Comment: @sumelic I don't understand your comment, pardon me if I'm not up to speed on the question and the answers, but the OP is asking if errorred could be considered correct in BrEng. Based on what? That *powered* doesn't have a double "r" before -ed?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I meant to reapond to " Is there a single case where the letter -r is not doubled before the suffix-ed in AmEng?"

Comment: @sumelic sorry I didn't read my earlier comment. All clear now.