# Word for when you're looking for something and it's in your hand

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What's the word for *when you're looking for something and it's in your hand or in front of you*?

Examples:

- Looking for your phone and it's in your hand.
- I had put on my spectacles and I was looking for them.

Does this phenomenon have a name?

Part of speech: it's a name of the phenomenon so it should be a noun. It can be a compound noun or a single word.

I searched many different things but did not find anything helpful.

Comment: This is a ... I had it right in hand but forgot what I was going to say ... Oh, yes!! "Senior moment"!

Comment: It doesn't exactly roll off the tongue, but *schotoma* might work. Or how about *hiding in plain sight*?

Comment: Answers will probably just duplicate those to [one word describing making an uncharacteristically stupid mistake](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/347823/one-word-describing-making-an-uncharacteristically-stupid-mistake/347877#347877).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, Just because there's a duplicate — which isn't really a duplicate of my question but contains the words that are posted in the answers to my question — doesn't mean the answers to my question deserve downvotes.

Comment: No, but if they fail to address the 'when you're looking for something and it's in your hand or in front of you?' directly and merely are repeats of synonyms for 'senior moment' / 'absentmindedness', I can't see how they add value to the site. Bloat should be discouraged; ELU aims to be a reasonably easily searchable resource –  imagine if CGEL say covered everything ten times. Note that I haven't downvoted the question, which does ask for a more specific term than the one I linked to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term you are looking for is called a *brain fart*.

**Brain fart:** (figuratively, slang, mildly vulgar) An instance of absent-mindedness or forgetfulness.

Example sentence: Sorry for the brain fart, but what exactly did you say again?

Senior moment or Mental lapse also work here.

Answer (score 1):

How about **absentmindedness**? From Lexico:

> **[absentminded](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/absentminded)**: (of a person or a person's behavior or manner) having or showing a habitually forgetful or inattentive disposition.

**Forgetfulness** could also work.

> **[forgetfulness](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/forgetfulness)**: lapse of memory

Examples of **absentmindedness** and **forgetfulness**:

> Looking for your phone and it's in your hand.
>
> I had put on my spectacles and I was looking for them.